# PyOpenCL, how to use exponential function, (OpenCL)

Tags: python, parallel-processing, opencl, pyopencl

I am writing this OpenCL code on Python using PyOpenCL that involves exponential function. However, I don't know how to include this library to make it work. So in the kernel, it is simply like this for example:

```
kernelsource = """
__kernel void forceFinder(
    const int N,
    __global float* datacl,
    __global float* poscl,
    __global float* res)
{
    int i = get_global_id(0); // Global id;
    if (i < N) {

         res[i] = (datacl[i ] - poscl[i]) *exp(100);

    }
}
"""
```

I tried to use (from pyopencl.clmath import exp) at the beginning but it doesn't work. When I tried to build the program it fail and give this:

```
<program source>:28:66: error: call to '__fast_relax_exp' is ambiguous
            res[i * dim + k] = (datacl[i * dim + k] - poscl[k]) *exp(0);
```

Please help.

Much appreciated

Jiajun

Comment: Have you tried `exp(100.f)`?

Comment: Dear doqtor, thank you so much!!! It works.....;